# Delete IP address alias by label name

Tags: linux, iproute

I would like to delete an alias I created using:

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 label eth0:100
```

without having to know the IP address. Basically, I would like to do

```
ip addr del dev eth0 label eth0.100
```

which, according to [documentation](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~read/iproute2.doc.html#ss9.2.2) should be valid, but rather gives me:

```
ip: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

In the mean time, I worked around using

```
ip addr del $(ip addr list label eth0:100 | awk '{ print $2 }') dev eth0 label eth0.100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is the best route (though I would use `grep` over `awk`, but that's personal preference). The reason being is because you can have multiple addresses per 'label'. Thus you have to specify which address you want to delete.

```
# ip addr help
Usage: ip addr {add|change|replace} IFADDR dev STRING [ LIFETIME ]
                                                      [ CONFFLAG-LIST ]
       ip addr del IFADDR dev STRING
       ip addr {show|save|flush} [ dev STRING ] [ scope SCOPE-ID ]
                            [ to PREFIX ] [ FLAG-LIST ] [ label PATTERN ]
       ip addr {showdump|restore}
IFADDR := PREFIX | ADDR peer PREFIX
          [ broadcast ADDR ] [ anycast ADDR ]
          [ label STRING ] [ scope SCOPE-ID ]
```

Note the `ip addr del` syntax which says the parameters are `IFADDR` and `STRING`. `IFADDR` is defined below that, and says `PREFIX` is a required parameter (things in `[]` are optional). `PREFIX` is your IP/subnet combination. Thus it is not optional.

---

As for what I meant about using `grep`, is this:

```
ip addr del $(ip addr show label eth0:100 | grep -oP 'inet \K\S+') dev eth0 label eth0:100
```

The reason for this is in case the position of the parameter changes. The fields positions in the `ip addr` output can change based on optional fields. I don't think the `inet` field changes, but it's just  my preference.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete net alias using `ifconfig` command:

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0:100 down
```

According to manual for `ip` command, only device name is required for IP address deletion. The rest arguments are optional. If no arguments given the first IP address will be deleted from the interface. But really I couldn't reproduce this behaviour.
Looks like the IP address is required too.

The last command you've shown works just because the expression `ip addr list label eth0:100 | awk '{ print $2 }'` gives the IP address of the net alias and insert this IP to `ip addr delete ...` command.

Answer (score 0):

`ip` command has `-o` flag which produces output suitable for parsing. For instance:

```
# ip -o addr show label wlp2s0:1|awk '{print $4}'
172.16.127.5/24
```

It is sufficient do wrap this as command-substitution `$(...)` and we have the following:

```
# ip addr del $(ip -o addr show label wlp2s0:1|awk '{print $4}') dev wlp2s0
```

Variation on the same theme but with `xargs`:

```
# ip -o a show label wlp2s0:1|awk '{print $4}'|xargs -I% ip a del % dev wlp2s0
```

Note that you can replace `addr` with `a` for shorter command

**Side note:**

Please note that for `ip` command this is the required syntax as per 2011 man-page [ip-address(8)](http://man.he.net/man8/ip-address)

```
ip address del IFADDR dev IFNAME
```

Hence the address with prefix has to follow `del` and `dev IFNAME` is required.